# DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147023728

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-phone, uwp-xaml

I was deploying my simple `UWP` app on `Windows Phone (Lumia 535)`

**Phone:** 
`Ver: 1607` - `Build : 10.014393.953`

**Target:**  (Enable Developer Mode - Phone & PC)

[image: tar]

**ERROR**

**`DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147023728`**

If I compile / run: `(ARM - Device)` Configuration

[image: run]

UPDATED: (I already turn this on - deploy)

[image: deploy]

I have this one already updated.

[image: updatedVS]

After tweaking some time I get this error:

[image: uap]

I tried to make a file and sideload it **-> Project -> Store -> Create Package**

My package was corrupted during phone manual installation.

I could not find anything related to this error in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=firefox-b-ab&q=DEP0001%20Unexpected%20Error%20%20-2147023728&oq=DEP0001%20Unexpected%20Error%20%20-2147023728&gs_l=serp.3...498189.502567.0.503304.4.4.0.0.0.0.178.696.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.g-4CKRUVZ2M&gfe_rd=cr&ei=KKHPWL_vDu_c8gfws6SgBA).

Comment: Is the phone in developer mode?

Comment: SLR, yes it is already in developer mode. :(

Comment: Check if `Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)` is enabled or not.

Comment: when I get such an error I just factory reset my testing device and it works for me.

Comment: @AdityaSharma - My windows device is not only for testing, I really use it. I was tempted to do the same thing.

Comment: @AVKNaidu - Ok, I will just type that in `cmd` ? I have MTP problem since that anniversary update. My device will not appear on File explorer.

Comment: Is SDK 10240 Installed on your system?

Comment: @AVKNaidu - in my `Local Machine` it is working but not on actual device. I didn't use Virtual, due to `Android` . I will check for SDK 10240 . I try to sideload the app, and it report that there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Third Screenshot, It looks like your App is not configured to deploy under `ARM` Configuration.

Click on the Dropdown next to Build Type(Debug\Release) And open Configuration Manager.

Make sure you have `Deploy` checked. Like in the screenshot Below.

[image]

Good Luck.

Comment: It is already checked in my case :( I will post a Screen Shot.